# 古いEclipse環境でのGooglePlayServicesのインストールと参照

Tags: eclipse, google-play-service

[[Android] SDKの古いバージョンr18環境の再構築メモ | SMK実験室](http://www.umek.topaz.ne.jp/smk/2012/08/android-sdk-r18rebuild.html)より、古いバージョンのeclipseの環境の構築が出来ましたが、Google Play Services API ライブラリのインストールやGoogle Play Services API ライブラリの参照が出来ません。
構築した環境をアップデートせずにライブラリの参照やインストールをするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？